# Querydsl: JPAUpdateClause with multiple sources

Tags: querydsl

I am new to Querydsl so the question might seem stupid to some of you :)

Here is what I want to do:

```
QAppt qApptRqst = QAppt.apptRqst;
QLocZip qLocZip = QLocZip.locZip;

JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);

JPAUpdateClause upd = new JPAUpdateClause(em, qApptRqst);
upd.where(qApptRqst.apptRqstStatusRef.apptRqstStatusCd.eq("U"),
qApptRqst.applZip5Cd.eq(qLocZip.usZip5Cd))
   .set(qApptRqst.uscisLocation.uscisLocCd, qLocZip.uscisLocCd)
   .execute();
```

I have following exception:

```
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Undeclared path 'locZipJuris'. Add this path as a source to the query to be able to reference it."
```

How do I use **JPAUpdateClause** with multiple sources?

Answer (score 1):

You could use subquery in your update statement as shown below.

```
upd.set(qApptRqst.xx, new JPASubQuery().from(qLocZip).where(qLocZip.usZip5Cd.eq(qApptRqst.applZip5Cd)).unique(qLocZip.locCd))
             .where((qApptRqst.apptRqstStatusRef.eq("NA")))
             .execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

JPA supports only a single source for DML updates, in your case a subquery might work.